# What's the Mercurial equivalent for git hash-object and how do I get the hash of a certain commit?

Tags: git, object, mercurial, hash

If I run git `hash-object` on a file, I can get it's SHA, and if I look around with `ls-tree` I can see what signature an object had at a certain revision. If I do three commits with Mercurial, of a file, can I see what hash the object had at the 2nd commit?

Can I see what hash the object has now? Even if it's modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `hg manifest --debug`? It prints all files in the current revision with their corresponding nodeids.

```
$ hg man --debug | head
9d2ea05fa708cb035dc716c071f0ad00c3449e1e 644   .hgignore
5199ce4ea50cd49c1757bf113c9239f4bf9e9de6 644   .hgsigs
6a6af229d3f6ce57cb7602f807069bf4f5febb32 644   .hgtags
7c8afb9501740a450c549b4b1f002c803c45193a 644   CONTRIBUTORS
02c5479e672e6a43116c48889101884f4b07ec25 644   COPYING
0fd39b23c59f01ef46a2805f1e9b8529246ea294 644   Makefile
780f5a706681ff4efab75c2beae6ee56f710a50b 644   README
```

Answer (score 3):

Mercurial works different internally. What you can see is the hash of the "[changeset](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangeSet)" - there is no "tree" of objects in mercurial, just a lot of files with a sequence of changesets.

`hg log` allows you to see the hash and the involved files. In your case, that would be `hg log -r -2` (show 2nd last commit) or `hg log -r -2 -v` if you want the list of files, too.

Comment: Would I need to work with the API to get the hash? I want to do a script that will tell me at which revision a file is. For example: I revert a file to the 2nd commit, run the script and see the rev.

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing: In Mercurial, you update a file to a certain revision using `hg update`. Use `hg log --template "{node}" --limit 1 -r` *revision* *filename* to get the hash for a specific revision of a file. No need to "revert". Instead of reverting/updating, have a look at `hg qimport` which can create a patch from the last few commits.